# Displaying post from specific category in WordPress

Tags: post, categories

I would like to display 5 post from a specific category on homepage. First one have to be with a Large thumbnail and excerpt and others 4 post with small image and post title.

Like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/utQ9s.png

Answer (score 0):

For that you will need to select specific template and edit it.

Free templates are not allowed to be editted by code but on the dashboard you can customize the visiblity of the site.

Are you having the same Template? If not then first select the specific template and you'll get this feature by default.